# Parsing a string with a start and end delimiter in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a text file with a large string of characters, like so:

```
starthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
endhere
```

Is there an efficient way this could be parsed from 'starthere' to 'endhere', returning all of the text in the middle? Eg. parsing the data using both a start and end delimiter?

My current idea is to delimit the whole text by 'starthere', and then delimit the remaining text by 'endhere' to return the middle text. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

I've been looking into string parsing in Batch, but it seems most built in tools are for single-character delimitation.

Comment: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35a

Comment: Of course you can also use a loop in pure bash, but that's not an efficient way.

Comment: if `sed '/starthere/,/endhere/{processing...}' file` doesn't work for you, then you need provide some more example data.

Comment: @Kent: that hat is absolutely perfect! ... and secret too ... nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/endhere/{f=0} f; /starthere/{f=1}' text

inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
```

or, if you want the delimiters as well

```
$ awk '/starthere/,/endhere/' text

starthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
inserttexthere
endhere
```